# Why am I getting There is a problem with this formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel 2019

I've been using Excel for years but I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error. It's the smallest little formula but the lovely and completely generic error isn't telling me what's wrong.

So I have a spreadsheet with a column (G) that is filled with TRUE or FALSE values. All I want to do is, in the next column (H), put a zero if it's G cell is FALSE and a 1 if it's TRUE. If I put in the H cell a formula that says =G2 it works and replicates the value. If I put =G2 = FALSE (for a FALSE value) then it correctly puts TRUE in the cell. However if I put the following statement in the cell I get the generic error "There is a problem with this formula": =IF(G2 = FALSE, 0,1)

It looks right to me but I can't figure it out. Why does the logical test work alone but not in an IF statement? I tried changing around the data types for the G and H columns with no love. I know it's stupid and I know I'm missing something but I just can't seem to get it working. If anyone can rent me a clue that would be lovely.

Thank you!

Comment: Are your locality settings correct?  It might be expecting `=IF(G2 = FALSE; 0;1)` which would give that error.

Comment: Also all you need is `=--G2`

Comment: Funny thing even `=INT(G2)` would work.

Comment: I still don't know why my formula didn't work but both =--G2 and =INT(G2) worked just fine. The semi's didn't do anything but I'm assuming that's because my localization settings are fine (USA). Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel TRUE & FALSE already have values attached to them, so as strange as it may seem just times it by one "=G2*1",that should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Had some great help on and I'm going to say that Scott Craner's answer is the one I used. It seems that double dash exists specifically to change TRUE and FALSE values to numbers. All of the following worked quite well. Thank you folks!

```
=--G2 (Scott Craner)
=INT(G2) (JvdV)
=G2*1 (Jim)
```

Comment: Sorry Scott. :)

Comment: Double dashes don't "exists specifically to change TRUE and FALSE values to numbers".  That's their effect, but not the reason why they exist. They perform a mathematical operation on the value, in this case the value in cell G2, just like multiplying by 1 performs a mathematical operation. You wouldn't say that Multiplication by One exists specifically to change TRUE and FALSE values to numbers. A single `-` changes the sign of a number to its opposite. Another `-` changes it back. When the value is text, this causes a text value to be turned into a number, just like multiplication by 1 does.